# Why these Keras Sequential model and Functional API act differently?

Tags: python, keras

I have a generator that yields data in a shape of `(32, 9, 200, 1)` where 32 is the batch size. The model for it is as follows:

```py
def create_model(le):
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=30, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, 200, 1)))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=10, activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

    model.add(LSTM(50))

    model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(len(le.classes_), activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(model.summary())

    return model
```

This model works well. In a second way, I yield data in a shape of 5x`(32, 9, 200, 1)`. The reason of `5x` is I yield a list of 5 arrays in order to feed a multi-input model. The model is as follows:

```py
def create_model():
    input_x = Input(batch_shape=(None, 200, 1), dtype='float32')

    conv_1 = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(20), activation='relu'))(input_x)
    maxpool_1 = TimeDistributed(MaxPool1D(pool_size=(4)))(conv_1)
    bn_1 = TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization())(maxpool_1)

    conv_2 = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(10), activation='relu'))(bn_1)
    maxpool_2 = TimeDistributed(MaxPool1D(pool_size=(4)))(conv_2)

    flatten = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(maxpool_2)

    lstm_1 = LSTM(50)(flatten)

    dense1 = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(lstm_1)
    out = Dense(units=32, activation='relu')(dense1)
    model = Model(input_x, out)

    inputA = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')
    inputB = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')
    inputC = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')
    inputD = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')
    inputE = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')

    cnn_out1 = model(inputA)
    cnn_out2 = model(inputB)
    cnn_out3 = model(inputC)
    cnn_out4 = model(inputD)
    cnn_out5 = model(inputE)

    combined = concatenate([cnn_out1, cnn_out2, cnn_out3, cnn_out4, cnn_out5], axis=-1)

    fully_connected = Dense(64, activation="relu")(combined)
    outputs_fc = Dense(13, activation="softmax")(fully_connected)

    model_encoded = Model(
        inputs=[inputA, inputB, inputC, inputD, inputE], outputs=outputs_fc)

    adamtopimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

    model_encoded.compile(optimizer=adamtopimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(model_encoded.summary())

    return model_encoded
```

But the second one gives an error, in the line of `conv_1`:

> ValueError: Input tensor must be of rank 3, 4 or 5 but was 2.

This error is being raised in `create_model`, so it's before the generator runs at all, so I don't think it's relevant to the generator I use.

Why it works well in the first one but fails in second one? I can give any information you need. Thanks.

**Edit-1:** If I change it to `input_x = Input(batch_shape=(None, 9, 200, 1), dtype='float32')` it still gives the error above.

Answer (score 1):

# Update on 4/14
Is this what you want?

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, TimeDistributed, LSTM, Concatenate, Dense, MaxPool1D, BatchNormalization, Flatten
from keras.models import Model

def create_model(input_shape=(9, 200, 1)):
    input_x = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')

    conv_1 = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(20), activation='relu'))(input_x)
    maxpool_1 = TimeDistributed(MaxPool1D(pool_size=(4)))(conv_1)
    bn_1 = TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization())(maxpool_1)

    conv_2 = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(10), activation='relu'))(bn_1)
    maxpool_2 = TimeDistributed(MaxPool1D(pool_size=(4)))(conv_2)

    flatten = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(maxpool_2)

    lstm_1 = LSTM(50)(flatten)

    dense1 = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(lstm_1)
    out = Dense(units=32, activation='relu')(dense1)
    model = Model(input_x, out)

    inputA = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
    inputB = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
    inputC = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
    inputD = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
    inputE = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')

    cnn_out1 = model(inputA)
    cnn_out2 = model(inputB)
    cnn_out3 = model(inputC)
    cnn_out4 = model(inputD)
    cnn_out5 = model(inputE)

    combined = Concatenate(axis=-1)([cnn_out1, cnn_out2, cnn_out3, cnn_out4, cnn_out5])

    fully_connected = Dense(64, activation="relu")(combined)
    outputs_fc = Dense(13, activation="softmax")(fully_connected)

    model_encoded = Model(
        inputs=[inputA, inputB, inputC, inputD, inputE], outputs=outputs_fc)

    model_encoded.summary()
    return model


create_model()
```

------------ Old answer below

You put wrong batch_shape in Input in second model. Document says,

> batch_shape: A shape tuple (integer), including the batch size. For instance, batch_shape=(10, 32) indicates that the expected input will be batches of 10 32-dimensional vectors. (https://keras.io/layers/core/#input)

```py
def create_model():
    input_x = Input(batch_shape=(32, 9, 200, 1), dtype='float32')
```

Also, Your posted first model has an input with arbitrary batchsize and (200, 1) size of tensor. See documentation:

> If you ever need to specify a fixed batch size for your inputs (this is useful for stateful recurrent networks), you can pass a batch_size argument to a layer. If you pass both batch_size=32 and input_shape=(6, 8) to a layer, it will then expect every batch of inputs to have the batch shape (32, 6, 8).  (https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#getting-started-with-the-keras-sequential-model)

You can change into

```py
def create_model(le):
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=30, activation='relu'), input_shape=(9, 200, 1), batch_size=32))
```

Comment: *You put wrong batch_shape in Input in second model.* What is the correct form should be? `None` specifies an arbitrary batch size. I don't specify 9 there because this is time distributed, so model will treat all `(200, 1)` tensors as timesteps. And as you see this approach works in the first model.

Comment: *Your posted first model has an input with arbitrary batchsize and (200, 1) size of tensor.* okay, is anything wrong with arbitrary batch size? What's the downside of not specifiying it?

Comment: None batchsize is ok. Doc says _If you ever need to specify a fixed batch size for your inputs (this is useful for stateful recurrent networks)_, but I haven't tried.  I think you have to specify 9 as in input.

Comment: _model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(8), input_shape=(10, 16)))_ in https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/ 
is an example. Dense usually get input as one dimension.

Comment: Nope, it actually didn't, I'm still stuck on that. But it deserves an upvote.